# jQuery won't display variable containing text with line brakes

Tags: jquery, newline

Why jQuery doesn't work when I have a variable with line breaks in it:

This works:

```
var text = "This is my text and it works fine";
```

This doesn't:

```
var text = "this is my text
            and it does not work";
```

Is there any way around this?
I'm trying to create a variable containing text from a database and it might contain line breaks, tags...

Comment: JS does not work with variables containing line-break. In my opinion you should sanitize that on your server-side, by using something like `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string);` (if you using PHP) so it will be preserved on your layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
var text = "this is my text";
   text += " and it does not work";
```

OR

```
var text = "this is my text" +
       " and it does not work";
```

OR

```
var text = "this is my text  \
       and it DOES  work now";
```

Answer (score 0):

Following way is correct -

```
var text = "this is my text " +
           "and it DOES  work now! ";
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ECBdz/)

Comment: the demo in fiddle does not eliminates tabs,spaces,intends. there's gap between `..my text` and `and it DOES...` in alert box.